# Date POST switching types

Tags: php, datetime

I don't know really how to elaborate on this problem. I have the following markup in my form:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="renewal" required="required" id="renewal" />
```

and if I call `var_dump` it tells me that it is a String value of the date formatted in a `Y-m-d` format. However, if I attempt to convert the String to a DateTime object using the following:

```
$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($_POST['renewal']);
```

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in *.php:212 Stack trace: #0 *.php(212): DateTime->__construct(Object(DateTime)) #1 {main} thrown in *.php on line 212

So if I try to explicitly convert `$_POST['renewal']` to a String using strval:

```
$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime(strval($_POST['renewal']));
```

I receive the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in *.php on line 212

And if I try to get the format from `$_POST['renewal']` using:

```
$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($_POST['renewal']->format('Y-m-d'));
```

I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string in *.php:212 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in *.php on line 212

And if I try to not do anything to the POST value and try to set the date's year to this year's value using the following:

```
$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($today->format('Y') . $_POST['renewal']->format('-m-d'));
```

I receive the same call to a member function error as shown above. So why does it tell me when I attempt to convert the POST value to a DateTime object that it expects a String and not a DateTime object, but whenever I try to use the value as a DateTime object it says that the object is a String?

**UPDATE**

To show you what I'm trying to do, I am trying to see if the value of `$_POST['renewal']` is greater than today's date. If the value of the POST greater than today's date then I'm changing the value to today's year and if the value is still not greater than today's date then I'm also adding 6 month's to the date. Here is the code that I'm trying to use:

```
$today = new DateTime("now");
$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($_POST['renewal']->format('Y-m-d'));

if ($_POST['renewal'] < $today) {
  $_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($today->format('Y') . $_POST['renewal']->format('-m-d'));
  if ($_POST['renewal'] < $today) {
    date_add($_POST['renewal'], date_interval_create_from_date_string('6 months'));
  }
}
```

The value that I'm using to test the code is `2016-06-28`, and what I expect it to do is change to `2018-06-28` and then again to `2018-12-28`. But if I send the value of `2017-11-01` then it would change to `2018-11-01` and if I send the value of `2018-12-01` then it would not change at all.

Comment: What PHP version? What's the output of `var_dump($_POST['renewal'])` right before you use it as argument for `DateTime()`?

Comment: what do you get with `strtotime($_POST['renewal'])`? Also post the var_dump result

Comment: That's weird are you using any framework?

Comment: @DanMan - I'm using PHP 7.1.22 and if I use `echo '<pre><code>', var_dump($_POST['renewal']), '</code></pre>'; exit();` right before I use it as an argument it returns: `string(10) "2018-06-28"`

Comment: @Ntwobike - Look at my previous comment to DanMan for the result, but if I use `echo '<pre><code>', strtotime($_POST['renewal']), '</code></pre>'; exit();` then it returns: `1530144000`

Comment: @Viney - No, I'm just using PHP.

Comment: I would commented everything else and just leave below code and try
`$renewalDate = new DateTime($_POST['renewal']);
var_dump($renewalDate);`

Comment: @Ntwobike - your suggestion to print the value of `strtotime` made me think to use `$renewal = new DateTime(); $renewal->setTimestamp(strtotime($_POST['renewal']));` and then set the value of the POST to `$renewal` and that worked too.

Comment: can u execute my above code snippet and commented out everything else. Divide and Conquer!

Comment: @Ntwobike - Yes, it prints the following: `object(DateTime)#4 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-06-28 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } ` why would it work for a new variable, but not with the existing POST variable?

Comment: Then its fine right?

Comment: @Ntwobike - Yeah, your suggestion worked. I just don't understand why it worked when assigning it to a new variable and it didn't when using an existing variable.

Comment: Error is hard say, you have to check with the line number while you experimenting. Theoretically `$_POST['renewal'] = new DateTime($_POST['renewal']);` Should not throw any errors.